# how to check the value of node is present which i want to read in xml

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

My program is reading the value from xml . The problem is that sometime some value are coming in the xml and sometime the value is not coming . At that time `object reference is not set an instant of object` error message i get. So  i want that if the value is not present in xml the value i do not want to assign the value to any variable. Below is my code for your review.

```
foreach (XElement AddressNode in ActivityLocationNode.Elements("Address"))
  {
   activitylocationtype.Address.City = AddressNode.Element("City").Value;
   activitylocationtype.Address.CountryCode = AddressNode.Element("CountryCode").Value;
   activity.ActivityLocation = activitylocationtype;
   activitylist.Add(activity);
   pakagetype.Activity = activitylist;
   pakagetypelist.Add(pakagetype);
   shipment.Package = pakagetypelist;
   shipmentlist.Add(shipment);
   trackresponse.Shipment = shipmentlist; }
```

The xml i am reading is below

```
<Address>

  <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
</Address>
```

in the code the Countrycode is coming but i am reading the City in first . So here i am getting the error.  Thanks for you for your comments.

Comment: Just check whether `AddressNode.Element("City")` is null or not before the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing `Value` property of `XElement`, you can instead cast it to `string` to avoid exception, for example :

```
//this will give you null because <City> is not found, and no exception
activitylocationtype.Address.City = (string)AddressNode.Element("City");
activitylocationtype.Address.CountryCode = (string)AddressNode.Element("CountryCode");
```